# UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp1027 with DB2 JDBC Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, character-encoding, db2

I am creating a simple database table with a column of type `Timestamp` on IBM DB2 on mainframes from a JDBC client like this-

```
CREATE TABLE scma.timetest(
            T_TYPE VARCHAR(8),
            T_DATE TIMESTAMP
            );
```

With or without inserting any record if I do a `select * from scma.timetest;` I end up getting the below exception-

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp1027
```

If I don't have the Timestamp type column, everything works fine. I have tried starting the JDBC client with  `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` with no avail. Same thing I tried from a Java program as well, it results in the same error.

It is not the same problem mentioned [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21569499), I don't get ClassNotFoundException. Any pointer what could be wrong. Here is full exception if it helps-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp1027
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.t.<init>(t.java:13)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.s.a(s.java:12)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.a(o.java:444)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cc.a(cc.java:2412)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:3513)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:2006)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:1931)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.m(cb.java:765)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.i(cb.java:253)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.c(cb.java:55)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.c(q.java:44)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.j(rb.java:147)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.kb(mn.java:2107)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.a(mn.java:3099)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.a(mn.java:686)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.executeQuery(mn.java:670)
```

Comment: Make sure  rt.jar is explicitly referenced in the runtime java class path

Comment: @Rehman it is there.

Comment: Which OS r u using ?

Comment: @Rehman it is Windows 7.

Comment: Do you mean the exception is thrown when you execute `statement.executeQuery("select * from scma.timetest")` as soon you add the column `T_DATE TIMESTAMP`? Have you checked that there is no trailing `;` in the select statement?

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes, that's the statement I execute from java code or from the JDBC client, tested with and without the trainling ;

Comment: @SubOptimal: I tried it testing with a different instance of DB2 where it doesn't cause the problem, so I believe it is something to do with the DB2 instance but that's strange.

Comment: Try creating the table using Unicode: `CREATE TABLE scma.timetest(...) CCSID UNICODE`

Comment: Can you check if you have a `charsets.jar` under the JRE's `lib` foder?

Comment: @mustaccio : Thanks mustaccio, CCSID UNICODE worked. Would you like to explain a little about it please and would be an option to create tables that way or some sort of global setting on the database would be required.

Comment: @Stavr00: charsets.jar is there.

Comment: Legacy DB2 for z/OS often use EBCDIC (also known as CP1027) encoding for character data. Also I believe DB2 sends timestamp values to the client as character strings, although they are internally stored differently. I suspect that the Java runtime that you are using does not support CP1027, so it doesn't know how to convert EBCDIC data to whatever it needs on the client. You (well, not you but the mainframe system programmers) can configure the default encoding scheme for the database (subsystem).

Comment: More details: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_introcodepage.dita?lang=en

Comment: @mustaccio :  Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving this here from comments:

Legacy DB2 for z/OS often use EBCDIC (also known as CP1027) encoding for character data. Also I believe DB2 sends timestamp values to the client as character strings, although they are internally stored differently. I suspect that the Java runtime that you are using does not support CP1027, so it doesn't know how to convert EBCDIC data to whatever it needs on the client. I cannot explain though why `VARCHAR` value comes through OK.

For more details about DB2 encoding you can [check the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_introcodepage.dita?lang=en).

You can force DB2 to create a table using different encoding, which will likely be supported by Java:

```
CREATE TABLE scma.timetest(...) CCSID UNICODE
```

Another alternative might be to use a different Java runtime that supports the EBCDIC (CP1027) encoding. The IBM JDK, which comes with some DB2 client packages, would be a good candidate.

You (well, not you but the mainframe system programmers) can also configure the default encoding scheme for the database (subsystem).